# Property with internal set and protected get

Tags: c#

I want to do so a variable (let's call it Foo) that can only be modified within the assembly but can be acessed by any child class, even outside the assembly
So I want to have an internal set and a protected get:

Doing `protected int Foo { internal set; get; }` tells me this that the set must be more restrictive than the property or indexer
But `internal int Foo { set; protected get; }` tells me the same thing for the get

How can I solve that?

Comment: I think you have to use [`protected internal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected-internal) for this.

Comment: But I don't want my get to be internal, only protected

Comment: @Timo sadly, that wont work, same error. Seems like you can't use protected internal on a setter

Comment: @MindSwipe `protected internal` means `protected` or `internal`. So both are now possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `internal` for the setter and `protected internal` for the whole property.

```
public class X
{
    // Read from this assembly OR child classes
    // Write from this assembly
    protected internal int Foo { internal set; get; }

}
```

The name `protected internal` is a bit misleading, but does what you want to achieve:

> A protected internal member is accessible from the current assembly or from types that are derived from the containing class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected-internal

So, because the setter is `internal`, you can set the property from anywhere in the same assembly but not from a different assembly. And because the property as a whole is `protected internal`, you can read it from anywhere in the same assembly OR from child classes in any assembly.

---

Another approach:

```
public class X
{
    // Read from child classes 
    // Write only from child classes in the same assembly
    protected int Foo { private protected set;  get; }

}
```

> A private protected member is accessible by types derived from the containing class, but only within its containing assembly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected

Comment: My issue is that I want the get to be only for child class, and protected internal also allow anyone from within same assembly to access it

Comment: @Xwilarg - ask yourself whether you *need* to prevent the `get` for the same assembly or you've just pursuing this out of some kind of "purity". Everything else within your assembly can *set* arbitrary values, but cannot, for instance, check the existing value before the set. Are you sure you need to preclude that possibility (in your own assembly even)?

Comment: @Xwilarg Would it be acceptable if only child classes in the same assembly can modify the property?

Comment: Not really but after thinking about Damien comment, I don't "absolutly" need to prevent people from within the same assembly to set values, what is the most important is to control what people from the outside do so your answer solve my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could create an internal method (or a proxy property) to call set on it.

```
protected int Foo { private set; get; }

internal void SetFoo(int foo)
{
    Foo = foo;
}
```

In this case you can set the setter of `Foo` to `private`.

Do note that this allows anything in your assembly that has a reference to this object can call `SetFoo`, which may not be what you want.